# Android Jetpack Compose - Best way to handle scrolling of entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

My screen has a horizontal gallery at the top (`LazyRow`) and beneath it has a grid of 8 buttons that can be scrolled (`LazyGrid`).

Due to the layout the grid when scrolled doesn't affect the gallery which makes sense.

What I'd like to do however is for the entire screen to scroll when I scroll the menu, as I scroll up, the gallery should disappear out of view.

I am thinking that the only way that I can get this done is to change the root `Column` into a `LazyColumn`.

Is there a better way? Should I be using a surface instead?

I did try adding the following to the Column's Modifier but that made no difference since my grid is itself scrollable.

`.scrollable(state = scrollState, orientation = Orientation.Vertical)`

This is my current code:

```
@Composable
fun MainMenuScreen(imageGalleryPaths: List<String>, menuItemList: List<MenuItem>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        MainMenuScreenBackgroundColorGradientStart,
                        MainMenuScreenBackgroundColorGradientEnd
                    )
                )
            )
    ) {
        HorizontalImageGallery(assetPaths = imageGalleryPaths)
        VerticalGridButtons(menuItems = menuItemList)
    }
}

@Composable
fun HorizontalImageGallery(assetPaths: List<String>) {
    LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.height(160.dp)) {
        items(assetPaths) { assetPath ->
            GalleryCard(assetPath)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VerticalGridButtons(menuItems: List<MenuItem>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(menuItems) { menuItem ->
            MenuItem(menuItem)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GalleryCard(model: String) {
    Card(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 0.dp, top = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
        .fillMaxSize(),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 8.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = model,
            contentDescription = "Porsche Gallery Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp)
                .padding(4.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite your code in a minimal example, it can be like this.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableScreenDemo() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        HorizontalImageGallery()
        VerticalGridButtons()
    }
}

@Composable
fun HorizontalImageGallery() {
    LazyRow {
        items(30) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VerticalGridButtons() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    ) {
        items(100) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .background(Color.DarkGray),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

To scroll the whole screen it can be rewritten like this,

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableScreenDemo() {
    VerticalGridButtons()
}

@Composable
fun HorizontalImageGallery() {
    LazyRow {
        items(30) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VerticalGridButtons() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    ) {
        item(
            span = {
                GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
            },
        ) {
            HorizontalImageGallery()
        }
        items(100) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .background(Color.DarkGray),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Changes**
Make the `LazyVerticalGrid` the parent and have the `HorizontalImageGallery` inside it with `GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)`.